# iOS 12 replacement for default Music-app which can "remember playback position"

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, mediaplayer, audiobook, ios

I upgrade from iPhone 4GS 16GB iOS 7.0.6 to iPhone 8 Plus 256GB iOS 12 
so i can put all my audiobooks on my phone.

but in new Music app **remember playback position** does not work anymore.
In iTunes it show **remember playback position set on** set on iphone music files.

So i need a replacement can do it.

I got over 680+ Audiobooks in my **iTunes Library** set as music type.
Why music type vs audiobooks are more tags show by default.
got 600+ 
Tags with 
Song`TrackName`+Artist`Author`+Album`Title`+Composer`Reader`+Genre+Year+Comments+Artwork`Bookcover`

I try audiobooks apps all i come over was lacking in display all info i want+easy search through i got over 600 audiobooks i does not want to move through all with scrolling max 5 books per scroll in scrolling no info.

I got over 70+ **Smart Playlist** on iTunes i like to use then fine right audiobook for time and day i want to hear audiobooks.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ecoute/id536882653 half like the interface but does not support **remember playback position**

Answer (score 1):

fine out after pay away ads does not support `.m4a` half iTunes Library are in this format thought it was a bug in app but after read app info... :( but fine other bug if to many files on app it crashes on startup!!

[FLAC Player+](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/flac-player+/id577346786?mt=8)

Good Old Music Interface:
`Song,Playlists,Artist,Album,Composer,Genre`

Got a **Setting** `Start Playing` turn from `From Beginning` to `Where Left Off`
that works! :)

No support for default iTunes Library sync.

Now copy all file through `https` or `iCloud-Drive` but vs start think switch to other different Phone it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

For the same functions you describe I use three apps on my iPhone and watch.

1. [Overcast](https://overcast.fm/) - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/overcast/id888422857
2. [Cesium Music Player](http://www.cesium-app.com/) - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cesium-music-player/id924491991
3. Music app plus Apple Music paid service - the iOS standard players which works with iTunes and enable me to sync all my iTunes libraries

I can't abide by having all the audio books in my iTunes library so I push them all to overcast and it does a fabulous job of downloading and cataloging and organizing. Cesium is the app which also has a dedicated audiobook player by the same developer - [greenlit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/greenlit-audiobook-player/id1360511601?mt=8). I know Cesium resumes my queue but since I don't listen to audiobooks from my library - you will have to check that greenlit or overcast maintains a current playback position for each and every title and not just the one title I listen to on occasion (where simply remembering the playback status of one file is all that's required).

For me, the reason I spent on cesium was it restored the interface I wanted to just focus on playlists and it has a toggle to only play songs that are downloaded since my cloud library has tens of thousands of tracks in "my library" and access to all the songs iTunes knows about. Sometimes I want to play from the library that's synced down like you have things with your iTunes Library being the source of the files.

Lastly - your tagging / organization / metadata request might be better as a new thread entirely once you have settled on a player. For me, using Siri to play the items I want is working great, but I don't know if you can curate your metadata well enough to have that work for your library.

Comment: if i switch track it remember playback position it was it on iOS 7 i try out cesium look 100% rich does fine way to enable remember ware i left off i switch back and forward between two tracks it forget all 10 time i try it out :( greenlit does remember playback position but look close to restricted interface ibooks and other auidobooksplayer-look-like, so it 3 way to fine right one, 1 search, 2 Scrolling , 3 some like play list but need manual adding of AudioBooks.
all metadata are in my language/style.

Comment: That makes good sense @K.D.G - you’ve got a very effective metadata and naming so you’ll likely need to make that work above all else.

Comment: yes over 10+ years perfect metadata system on iTunes.
can not live without it :-(

Comment: Wait... how do you "push [your audiobooks] to overcast"?

Comment: If you're a premium subscriber you can upload files to Overcast.

Answer (score 0):

Apps such as Ecoute and Cesium use the Apple's Music app to handle the playback, so you will find the same issue with remembering playback position.

A few options would be:

1. Overcast - as mentioned you can sideload up to 2GB books with a
   premium subscription. The web upload might be a bit limited for your
   needs though
2. Castro - sideload books with a subscription with no limitation other than your iCloud Drive storage space
3. Downcast - sideload books via iTunes File Sharing (first reveal the mp3 or m4a in Finder then drag it over), or import the files from Music app
4. Documents by Reaadle - sideload via iTunes or cloud storage such as iCloud Drive, Dropbox, etc. (you can turn on "remember media position" in settings)

All of the above will remember playback position and all except Castro can search based on title. But I don't think any of these will let you view/search all the tags.